# Rabbit mq 2.1.3 version

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers

I am getting below error while consuming message on rabbit mq through fanout approach :

2022-08-24 12:53:29.559 ERROR 42 --- [2.20.43.29:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'avitas.nodedata' in vhost 'avitas': received 'topic' but current is 'fanout', class-id=40, method-id=10)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like misconfiguration. RabbitMQ exchanges are immutable and error says that `avitas.nodedata` exchange has `fanout` type, however, consumer expects that it should have `topic` type.

If we consider rabbit spring cloud integration then if we initially had the following configuration:

```
  spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings:
    channel:
      consumer:
        exchangeType: fanout
```

And then changed exchange type to different one

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings:
    channel:
      consumer:
        exchangeType: topic
```

Then, we would have exchange with `fanout` type in RabbitMQ, and consumer that expects the same exchange with `topic` type.